# React Native (Android) - cannot find symbol class ReactInstanceManager

Tags: react-native

I just upgraded to React Native `0.63.3`.....I also upgraded Android studio to `4.1.1` and gradle plugin to `4.1.0`.
Im getting the error `cannot find symbol class ReactInstanceManager` when I try to build.
The error is in file `MainApplication.java`.....see code below.

Appears the error is with the line `initializeFlipper(this,getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());`.
It seems to be saying that Im providing `com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager`....but what the program wants is `ReactInstanceManager`.  
It says `Get the current ReactInstanceManager instance, or create one.`

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         * We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper, since
         * Flipper library is not available in release mode
         */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.xs.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
```

Answer (score 14):

I missed a single line of code during my upgrgade of RN from 0.61.5 to 0.63.3.  
`import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;` was missing from MainApplication.java

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have same package name as in your **`MainApplication.java`**.

Example :

```
package com.appname;
```

For same in:

```
android/app/src/debug/java/com/appname/ReactNativeFlipper.java
```

and in

```
android/app/src/release/java/com/appname/ReactNativeFlipper.java
```

This solved my issue since I have changed my package name.

Answer (score 2):

Not an ideal solution, but it worked for me:

I created file `ReactNativeFlipper.java` in
`android/app/src/main/java/com/myProject/` and put this code inside:

```
package com.myProject;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
public class ReactNativeFlipper {
  public static void initializeFlipper(Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    // Do nothing as we don't want to initialize Flipper on Release.
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36060

Note: Don't forget to change myProject to your project's name

Comment: I saw we need put to release folder, not `src` folder